# Exhaustive search times: 2 to power k = 100 hours - double k, how many hours

Tags: logarithms, cryptography

An exhaustive search (i.e. checking all combinations of values) takes 100 hours to go through all permutations where a binary key has a length of k.

$2^k$ = 100 hours where k is the number of digits in the binary key and 2 is the base (0 or 1).

If the length of the key is increased to 2k. How long will it take?

i.e. $2^{(2k)}$ = ? hours

Comment: What do you think? What's the difference between AES-128 and AES-256?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma 100^2 = 10000 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{2k} = 2^k \cdot 2^k$, so your answer in the comments is right.